# How to convert an array to string and sort it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to split the following array called Coordinates into two group of Strings
as follow ,but i don't think how to do it.

what i have i an array which get latitudes and longitudes

```
var latidudes_from_db = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".a"), input => input.value);
 var longitudes_from_db = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".b"), input => input.value);

   console.log(latidudes_from_db); 
console.log(longitudes_from_db);
```

//concated two arrays

```
      var coordinates = latidudes_from_db.concat(longitudes_from_db);
    console.log(coordinates);
```

**output i get is the mix of  longitudes and latitudes**

array :  Coordinates

```
  0:"-1.951"
  1:"-1.942"
  2:"30.095"
  3:"30.095"
   ...
  n:  "number"
```

Desired output in String is to match latitude with its own longitude and i thing it can be like this:

```
          var coodinate1 =   value of position 0  , value of position 0+2
          var coordinate2 =  value of position 0 + 1 , value of position 0+3
       .....
```

Comment: please add the data structure of source data and the wanted result.

Comment: what happens if there are 4,5,6... cordinates?

Comment: `var coodinate1 = [arr[0], arr[2]]`

Comment: @gramanda, have a look to my answer updated.

Comment: @Jonasw  if there is  4,5,6  i need it to be dynamic , so that if  ther is 4,5 for example it can `coordinate1` can not change , `coordinate2` can change too but `coordinate3` can be  : `position 0 + 3` , `position 0+4`

Comment: @gramandagrandish i dont get it. please add a valid input/expected output to your question

Comment: why do you var coordinates = latidudes_from_db.concat(longitudes_from_db), if you need to split them up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't concat() the 2 arrays , map the latitudes array instead and match the appropriate longitude by index

```js
var   lats = ["lat-1", "lat-2", "lat-3", "lat-4", "lat-5"],
  lons = ["lon-1", "lon-2", "lon-3", "lon-4", "lon-5"],
  strings = lats.map((lat, i) => [lat, lons[i]].join());



console.log(strings.join('\n'))
```

Comment: no need to split the array, OP has concated it ... :/

Comment: @Jonasw right...is a new edit that didn't show source before

Comment: @thanks for help sir, it seems to be magic , what `lat, i` stand for ? i'm sorry i'm beginner with Jquery but you can explain this line for me : `strings = lats.map((lat, i) => [lat, lons[i]].join())`

Comment: See [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @gramandagrandish, why my method it's not good ? Makes the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` method in order to do this.

`reduce` method accepts as parameter a `callback` method which is a provided function applied on every item in the array.

First half of the array represents `latitudes` and second half represents `longitudes`.

You have to group strings like `[arr[0],arr[2]]`, `[arr[1],arr[3]]`, `[[arr[2],arr[4]]`.

Generally you have `[arr[i],arr[arr.length/2]+i]`.

```js
var array=["-1.951","-1.942","30.095","30.095"];
array=array.reduce(function(contor,item,index){
  if(index<array.length/2)
    contor.push([array[index],array[array.length/2]+index]);
  return contor;
},[]);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: @Alexandru-lonut Mihai    , Thank you after what i see you divided the lenght of array into two and result is an array too . But what i wish to have is  an output of string if if  lenght of array increase the function continues to be dynimic like if there is  4 and  5th number,..   ,  for example it can `coordinate1` can not change , `coordinate2` can change too but `coordinate3` can be  : `position 0 + 3` , `position 0+4`

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: i edited the code , i thing now you are going to get me simply. take a simple review please

Comment: @gramandagrandish, have a look to my answer.

Comment: @Many Alexandru-Ionut Mihai   thanks